# Sqlite3 query not running properly on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a query like this

```
SELECT value1 FROM mytable where (value1 > value2) AND category = 1 ;
```

This is not executing properly in Android. Although if i manually go to

```
/data/data/packagename/databases/mydatabase.db
```

Here is the Code

```
try {
SQLiteDatabase sqdb = _context.openOrCreateDatabase(_DB_NAME, 0,
                null);
String sql = null;
sql = "SELECT value1 FROM mytable where (value1 > value2) AND category = " + category
                +"; ";
Cursor c = sqdb.rawQuery(sql, null);
Log.i("sql = ", sql);

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
while (!c.isAfterLast()) {

categoryValue = c.getString(0);
c.moveToNext();
}
}
Log.i("categoryValue", categoryValue);
sqdb.close();
c.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And then execute it. Then it works perfectly fine.

What is happeneing?

Comment: How it is behaving? What is the error? tell something?

Comment: It doesnt retrieve me the value of value1 if condition is true.....

Comment: Show us how you are executing in code?

Comment: is your `category` type string?

Comment: @Waqas Its Create table if not exists mytable (category integer, value1 double, value2 double) ;

Comment: whats the LogCat/error upon execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe first you need to close *cursor* and then the *database connection*

```
//the order should be
c.close();
sqdb.close();
```

Comment: Still Didnt work.. And i am not getting any error.. Its just not retrieving any values.... giving me "" only... :(

Comment: try logging `c.getCount();` and see how many records are actually fetched by your query? Just log it right after executing rawQuery

Comment: Its giving count to "0"... But if i run the same query through console then it is giving me the correct value....

Comment: Actually When i ran it first time then the condition was getting false and i wasnt getting any error. On the second time when i tried on console then the values changed and condition was getting true... :)...Totally My Mistake....